# Flexisip installed On centOs 7 but can not register to it

Tags: sip, sip-server

Hi every body I had to install Flexisip server on CentOS 7 and it running with no error as show below but when I try to register to the server no luck and I do not know what the error to that ?

service are running:

[image]

and the phone are registered to the sip.linphone.org successfully but with my server are no luck screen shot

[image: IOS smulator]

and for there server are running like a boss so any idea or what the issue for it and I try all of there readme and no luck to it

help please if you face this problem !

Comment: please remove iOS tag - your issue is in misconfigured server not in platform

Comment: done i rmove it